# I am trying to upload image but it seems like i can't send it to the server

Tags: reactjs, image

I am trying to select the image and send it to the server but when i send it, it says that the field file is empty. The same issue happens if i don't use the `FormData`. [Screen Shot](https://hmp.me/cn64).

My code:

```
import axios from "axios";
import React, { Component } from "react";
export default class UploadImage extends Component {
    handleChange= async (event)=>{
        const img = event.target.files[0]
        console.log(img)
        const fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('image',img, img.name)
        console.log(fd)
        const res = await axios.post(`http://localhost:5000/upload`,{file:img})
        // console.log(res)
    }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div class="custom-file mb-3">
            <input id="img" type="file" name="file"  class="custom-file-input" onChange={this.handleChange}/>
            <label for="file" class="custom-file-label">Choose File</label>
          </div>
       </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you have to set your request content-type header accordingly

Comment: Is it returning some string(base64)? If possible can you show, what's it(your img) looks like.

Comment: no nothing is received at the server [image](https://hmp.me/cn66)

Comment: @YahiaBadr Please go through this url https://codeburst.io/react-image-upload-with-kittens-cc96430eaece . It might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was at 2 parts:

1) `fd.append('image',img, img.name)` the first field must be equal to the field in the backend `upload.single('file')` since `"image"` and `"file"` does not match so it makes a problem.

2) at the axios requests `await axios.post("http://localhost:5000/upload",{file:img})`
the second field has to be only the `formdate` variable so it should be, `await axios.post("http://localhost:5000/upload",fd)`